# How to set the default date format in datepicker

Tags: angularjs

I am using ui-utils from angularjs and using date calender.

I am using 
`<input id="maxValue" data-ui-jq="datepicker" data-ui-options="{ dateFormat: 'd/m/yy' }" data-ng-model="selectedQuestion.maxValue" class="form-control">`

This does works fine when I select the date and it gives me the proper output.

```
27/8/2014
```

But when I had set the default date before selecting any date it gives me this date format.

```
Sun Feb 01 2099 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

How can I format this date on the load with the help of datepicker directive ?

Comment: Can you please show us code how you are setting the 'set the default date before selecting any date'? Are you setting the 'selectedQuestion.maxValue' to a date or a number value?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `dateFormat` keyword with `format`.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="maxValue" data-ui-jq="datepicker" data-ui-options="{ format: 'd/m/yy' }"
```

data-ng-model="selectedQuestion.maxValue" class="form-control">

this will work fine